# add bottom line to UIButton - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I use the extension to UIButton and I added it to my UIButton but I still can't see the line.

I'm missing something, please help

extension:
https://gist.github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/496d5713e61125bddcf5

my code:

```
    let settingsButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Settings", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

    button.addBorder(side: .Bottom, color: .white, width: 100)
    
    return button
}()
```

I want to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: set `attributedTitle` instead of `title` and use `NSAttributedString` with underline thats it

Comment: You mean u need bottom border to your button? or you need underline to button title?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I don't want to underline the text, just have lines under the button

Comment: It is probably UITableViewCell, not UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `UIView` that has [x] points height and same width as the button, and its y position is the same as the height of the button.

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: button.frame.size.height, width: button.frame.size.width, height: 2)
let borderBottom = UIView(frame: frame)
borderBottom.backgroundColor= UIColor.white
button.addSubview(borderBottom)
```